# How to create independent pages via react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I came from Angular framework to React and I got confused with router library. I'm trying to create Login page as a separate page in my app which is should contain Navigation and Footer which is part of Main.

I added this code to solve it but run into trouble.

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';
import Login from './containers/Login';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/">
      <App />
    </Route>

    <Route path="/login">
      <Login />
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
//app.js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/">
              <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/admin">
              <Admin />
            </Route>
          </Switch>

          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `react-router-dom` library.

So the main idea is I desire to load /login page without Navbar and Footer but for other pages in my app like Admin, Dashboard I want them to load with Navbar and Footer (I don't want use conditional rendering here).

But now when I go to /login page I see Navbar and Footer, also I can't go to dashboard.

Comment: Use `<Switch/>`  along with `exact` props to `<Route/>` Component , to render only one route at a time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';
import Login from './containers/Login';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      
      <Route path="/">
        <App />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```js
//app.js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />

          <Switch>

            <Route path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/admin">
              <Admin />
            </Route>
            
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
            </Route>

          </Switch>

          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work, but after page reloading when path is localhost/dashboard nothing happens, even Navbar and Footer didn't loaded

Comment: oh, sorry, "exact" props should be removed in index.js. I modified the source

Comment: Again it works, but when i come to localhost:/login i see Navbar and Footer component which is part App (localhost/*empty*)

Comment: Did you use the "Switch" component in index.js?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `exact` property to the route element

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is the best practice to place the root path('/') with ëxact props at the later route just before NotFoundPage.
I think it is the same as in Angular router.